# Swig Php and enable_dl

Tags: php, c++, linux, swig

I am using swig to create a php sdk. My package is a .so and a php file.

To be able to load the shared library PHP requires the user of the sdk to edit `/etc/php/<#.#>/cli/php.ini` with `enable_dl = On?`

**Is there any alternative to this? Possibly in code or per run?**